# How do I merge two columns in a dataframe by running both a left and right outer join

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have two tables with 2 columns each, one id column and one income column. I've joined both tables using a full outer join, doing the following:

```
val income = incomeA.join(incomeB, incomeA("idA") === incomeB("idB"), "full")
```

resulting in the following set:

```
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+----------+ 
|  idA               |  A_INCOME|  idB               |  B_INCOME|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+----------+
|0d4f671c-552b-449...|      2250|                null|      null|
|9e03f92e-af0e-416...|      1250|                null|      null|
|                null|      null|c75d0d17-f3c1-497...|      4300|
|02572d79-bc54-427...|      2880|                null|      null|
|                null|      null|ca493eca-0709-4db...|      2320|
|cb7831ac-2550-435...|      1650|                null|      null|
|da7ac4c4-403b-466...|      2250|                null|      null|
|9bddb7b5-0047-4e1...|      5170|                null|      null|
|                null|      null|b54fc648-5f00-411...|       800|
|7aeade0a-47d4-459...|      4250|                null|      null|
|4fde8deb-a7de-45a...|      1650|                null|      null|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+----------+
```

But instead of the above I would like the final result to contain 3 columns, one id column with both idA and idB and the two income columns, like so:

```
+--------------------+----------+----------+ 
|  id                |  A_INCOME|  B_INCOME|
+--------------------+----------+----------+
|0d4f671c-552b-449...|      2250|      null|
|9e03f92e-af0e-416...|      1250|      null|
|c75d0d17-f3c1-497...|      null|      4300|
|02572d79-bc54-427...|      2880|      null|
|ca493eca-0709-4db...|      null|      2320|
|cb7831ac-2550-435...|      1650|      null|
|da7ac4c4-403b-466...|      2250|      null|
|9bddb7b5-0047-4e1...|      5170|      null|
|b54fc648-5f00-411...|      null|       800|
|7aeade0a-47d4-459...|      4250|      null|
|4fde8deb-a7de-45a...|      1650|      null|
+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

That table should essentially be the result of both doing a full left join as well as a full right one on that dataframe. Is there a way to achieve this? How would you approach this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  It doesn't support `full join`, so you cannot be using that database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, a.income as a_income, b.income a b_income
from a full join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Most databases support the standard `USING` syntax, so you could also use:

```
select id, a.income as a_income, b.income a b_income
from a full join
     b
     using (id);
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot! That did the job! For anyone interested, this is what I did to adapt the above fo spark:
`incomeA.join(...).select( 
          coalesce(incomeA("idA"), incomeB("idB")).as("accountId"),
          col("A_INCOME"),
          col("B_INCOME")
        )`